# StringTemplate: skipping trailing coma when generating a Javascript array

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I'm generating a Javascript array in StringTemplate 4 and I'm having trouble skipping the trailing coma after last element. 
Each item gets generated using a template and then I want to separate them using comas to create an array in the form:

```
[ item1, item2, item3, item4 ]
```

Currently, my best shot at generating this array is this:

```
array(elems) ::= <<
  [ 
    $first(elems):elem_noComa()$
    $rest(elems):elem()$
  ]
>>

elem_noComa(el) ::= <<  { ...element generation... } >>

elem(el) ::= <<
  , $elem_noComa(el)$
>>
```

Is there a way to do it easier/in a shorter form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

does this work for you?

```
<elems:itemTemplate(); separator=",">
```

It applies itemTemplate() to each element of elems array and using "," in between.
Terence

Comment: Thank you very much Professor Parr. Silly of me. I was expecting this to work differently and must have not even checked this correctly. The above works. Marking as answer. Nice to meet you by the way :) Greetings from the royal city of Kraków.

Comment: Glad to help! Greetings from San Francisco.